# Can't reproduce L1-score from LightGBM

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm

When I run LGBM with early stopping, it gives me the scores corresponding to its best iteration.

When I try to reproduce these scores myself, I get different numbers.

```
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold


data = load_breast_cancer()
X = pd.DataFrame(data.data)
y = pd.Series(data.target)

lgb_params =  {'boosting_type': 'dart', 'random_state': 42}

folds = KFold(5)

for train_idx, val_idx in folds.split(X):
    X_train, X_valid = X.iloc[train_idx], X.iloc[val_idx]
    y_train, y_valid = y.iloc[train_idx], y.iloc[val_idx]
    model = lgb.LGBMRegressor(**lgb_params, n_estimators=10000, n_jobs=-1)
    model.fit(X_train, y_train,
              eval_set=[(X_valid, y_valid)],
              eval_metric='mae', verbose=-1, early_stopping_rounds=200)
    y_pred_valid = model.predict(X_valid)
    print(mean_absolute_error(y_valid, y_pred_valid))
```

I was expecting that

```
valid_0's l1: 0.123608
```

would match my own calculation from `mean_absolute_error`, but it doesn't. Indeed, here is the top part of my output:

```
Training until validation scores don't improve for 200 rounds.
Early stopping, best iteration is:
[631]   valid_0's l2: 0.0515033 valid_0's l1: 0.123608
0.16287265537021847
```

I'm using version '2.2.1' of lightgbm.

Comment: by changing 'boosting_type': 'dart' to 'gbdt' you will be able to get the same result. I will look to dart doc to find something about it.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this on the breast cancer dataset, but on my own dataset I ran into the same issue when using `gbdt` on some folds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update your LGBM version, you will get

> "UserWarning: Early stopping is not available in dart mode"

please refer to [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1893) for details about it. What you can do is to retrain a model using the best number of boosting rounds.

```
results = model.evals_result_['valid_0']['l1']
best_perf = min(results)
num_boost = results.index(best_perf)
print('with boost', num_boost, 'perf', best_perf)    
model = lgb.LGBMRegressor(**lgb_params, n_estimators=num_boost+1, n_jobs=-1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, verbose=-1)
```